# Facebook PHP. after login and redirect, user needs to manually refresh page

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I'm having a problem with a user logging in:

1) click facebook login button

2) user fills in information on facebook site

3) user is redirected to my site

4) this code is then run:

```
if ($user) 
{       
    try 
    {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $fb_user_id = $user_profile['id'];
        ...
```

The api call fires an error:

**OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.**

5)the user is treated as if they never logged in.

6)manually refreshing the page causes the session to be recognized and the api call does not throw an error.

What is going on? do I need to put a delay in?

Comment: What you using to handle login? `Facebook::getLoginUrl` (PHP-SDK) or `FB.login` (JS-SDK)?

Comment: $user = $facebook->getUser();

Comment: I meant something other. What your login button does? It is `fb:login-button`, link created with `getLoginUrl` or have `FB.login` binded on click?

Comment: Sorry misread that. I use getloginurl...which seems to have its own problem of not wanting to redirect, via next or redirect_uri params: `$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('next' => 'http://www.%%%.com/facebook_login.php');` `$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri' => 'http://www.%%%%.com/facebook_login.php'));` That ancillary problem aside, even with the example php file from the sdk, i must refresh the page for it to say logged in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was using the FB JS library incorrectly.

**EDIT :**
 I don't remember the specifics, but I'll try my best

I'm using the php SDK to see if a user is logged in through facebook, and if it is, save a session and store cookies. The JavaScript SDK is being used to log in a user through facebook then callback to a login page to update my server and store session variables. From what I can remember something was called out of order giving me a getuser problem. After re-reading the example files given with the sdk, it began to work.

Comment: That's not a good solution for someone using the PHP SDK.  Besides the undesirable Javascript dependency, if you use the PHP SDK (->getLoginUrl()) to log in, then use the JS SDK to refresh the page after login, there's a period of time after the login when the user is wondering if the login worked.  The user has time to click on links and interact with the page before being suddenly redirected in the middle of an action.

Answer (score 0):

I may have the answer for you.
After fiddling with the same issue (after successful login, no refresh).
I tried adding window.location.reload() upon login event to no avail

this, however, seems to do the trick for me:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    window.location.href=window.location.href;
}
```